# WooCommerce - related products by tags and categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, related-content

I want to display 8 "related products" in every product page of my site based on tags. But if there are less than 8 results fill the gaps with products in the same Categories.

Here is code that I'm using for showing only tag-related products (`functions.php`):

```
//New "Related Products" function for WooCommerce
function get_related_custom( $id, $limit = 5 ) {
global $woocommerce;

// Related products are found from category and tag
$tags_array = array(0);
$cats_array = array(0);

// Get tags
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'product_tag');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $tags_array[] = $term->term_id;

// Get categories (removed / commented)
/*
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'product_cat');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
 */

// Don't bother if none are set
if ( sizeof($cats_array)==1 && sizeof($tags_array)==1 ) return array();

// Meta query
$meta_query = array();
$meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();
$meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();

// Get the posts
$related_posts = get_posts( apply_filters('woocommerce_product_related_posts', array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => $limit,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
            'field'        => 'id',
            'terms'        => $cats_array
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
            'field'        => 'id',
            'terms'        => $tags_array
        )
    )
) ) );
$related_posts = array_diff( $related_posts, array( $id ));
return $related_posts;
}
add_action('init','get_related_custom');
```

Comment: Create 2 queries one based on tags and one based on categories, then check the number of posts with post_count , `if( $category_query->post_count > 8 ) ...... `

Answer (score 2):

The function you wrote is now discontinued ([see this in GitHub](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/legacy/abstract-wc-legacy-product.php))

([As we can read here](https://nicolamustone.blog/2015/03/02/hide-related-products-by-category-or-tag-in-woocommerce/)), you can add *one* of two snippets in **functions.php** file in **wp-content/themes/theme-name/**.

If you want to hide related products by tag, add this:

```
/**
 * Does not filter related products by tag
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_tag', '__return_false' );
```

or add this, if you want to hide related products by category:

```
/**
 * Does not filter related products by category
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category', '__return_false' );
```

After this, you might need to clear your transients to see a result (or wait for their expiration).

If you add both snippets (as in the other answer), your related products would be empty, because they won't be populated from tags and from categories

Comment: It is mandatory to clear transients so as to see changes. Thank you

Comment: @MohamedOmar your comment saved me from wasting a lot of time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open your **functions.php** file in **wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/** and add this code at the end of the file:

```
/**
 * Does not filter related products by tag
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_tag', '__return_false' );

/**
 * Does not filter related products by category
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category', '__return_false' );
```