# Change related products category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ok so i have this shop, there are two categories, one category has the upper hand on sales, and i want to promote the second category.

I would like to use the related products to promote them (i could use uppersells but there are 200+ products, and i dont want to edit them manually)

So i would like that, when viewing products of the first category, products from the second category appear in related products.

I'm pretty sure there's a quick way to achieve this in the related.php file in the theme, but my programming skills are poor, i've been scratching my head for hours on this, trying hard using bits and pieces i found here and there, but without luck for now, and i would take any advice on how to achieve this goal, if you please.

I even bought a module supposed to make me achieve this goal, turned out to be a rip off... does not work as intended at all.

Comment: Have a look at this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/31122389/515114
This should get you going

Answer (score 0):

I have a woocommerce store and I accomplish the exact thing you are looking for by using this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-related-items/screenshots/

Comment: The module you suggest is outdated, i just want to slightly change the behavior of related products, not replace it completly by another, outdated plugin. Replacing implies CSS styling, and time to set things up. Not what i am looking for.